# How to baypass "exceeded daily limit of downloads" while scraping data

Tags: r, web-scraping, proxy

I am building forecasting tool which works on historical stock database. I have problem with downloading all the historical prices from https://stooq.pl

My R code works fine, but I don't know how to baypass download limitation (problem occurs above ~40 downloads I need like 450). Code bellow:

```
stock<-c("06n", "08n", "11b", "1at", "4fm", "aal", "aat", "aba", "abc", "abe", "abm", "abs", "acg", "acp", "act", "adv", "ago", "agt", "ahl", "alc", "ali", "all", "alm", "alr", "amb", "amc", "aml", "ape", "apl", "apn", "apr", "apt", "arc", "arh", "arr","06n", "08n", "11b", "1at", "4fm", "aal", "aat", "aba", "abc", "abe", "abm", "abs", "acg", "acp", "act", "adv", "ago", "agt", "ahl", "alc", "ali", "all", "alm", "alr", "amb", "amc", "aml", "ape", "apl", "apn", "apr", "apt", "arc", "arh", "arr","06n", "08n", "11b", "1at", "4fm", "aal", "aat", "aba", "abc", "abe", "abm", "abs", "acg", "acp", "act", "adv", "ago", "agt", "ahl", "alc", "ali", "all", "alm", "alr", "amb", "amc", "aml", "ape", "apl", "apn", "apr", "apt", "arc", "arh", "arr") #example
Dane<- list()
i=1
for(c in stock){
  Dane[[i]]<-read.csv(url(paste("https://stooq.pl/q/d/l/?s=",c,"&i=d",sep="")))
  i=i+1
}
```

After ~40 downloads this error appears:
`[1] Przekroczony.dzienny.limit.wywolan` (you have exceeded daily limit of downloads) - It is not a real error, program is scraping file without data, only this message inside.

Is there a way to baypass this error? I don't know different webpage (I am not sure if there is any at all) from which I can download data I need.

Comment: Can you see whether the company that provides the data allows a paid service to provide greater access? (Don't read Polish/don't want to use Google translate and dig through the web page myself.)

Comment: There is no information about paid service (It is possible to create account to comment).

Comment: @BenBolker I double checked it, the only one paid service is to turn off adds on website.

Comment: _"I want help violating a site's Terms of Service & security measures. I know full well that LinkedIn and other companies have sued folks for doing this very thing but I want to bring you all down with me if I get into legal trouble."_

Comment: to rephrase @hrbmstr's comments: no, you seem to be stuck. Other than finding an unethical way around this particular web site's limitations (which we won't help you with: see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274906/should-questions-that-violate-api-terms-of-service-be-flagged ), your only option is to wait a day between downloads, or find another source of information.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about an unsolvable, non-programming question (handling limitations of terms of service of a third-party web site)

Comment: @BenBolker, in that case I will try to find another source od data, thanks for help :)

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get your link to work.  Anyway, take a look at this one.

http://investexcel.net/multiple-stock-quote-downloader-for-excel/

[image]

Obviously it's Excel, not R, but it does a nice job.  In addition, you can try something like this.

```
codes <- c("MSFT","SBUX","S","AAPL","ADT")
urls <- paste0("https://www.google.com/finance/historical?q=",codes,"&output=csv")
paths <- paste0(codes,"csv")
missing <- !(paths %in% dir(".", full.name = TRUE))
missing

# simple error handling in case file doesn't exists
downloadFile <- function(url, path, ...) {
# remove file if exists already
if(file.exists(path)) file.remove(path)
# download file
tryCatch(
download.file(url, path, ...), error = function(c) {
# remove file if error
if(file.exists(path)) file.remove(path)
# create error message
c$message <- paste(substr(path, 1, 4),"failed")
message(c$message)
}
)
}
# wrapper of mapply
Map(downloadFile, urls[missing], paths[missing])
```

Comment: Thanks for help but I need data from Polish market which is not available on google finance nor yahoo finance :( I come up with an idea of downloading datasets within download limits (~40 datasets per day). I have almost finished :)